# Change navigation bar title from text entered in a text field with Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, navigationbar

I want the title at the top of my page in the navigation bar to change based on the text entered into a specific text field. Would I do that through a separate UINavigationController or in the UIViewController, and if so how would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a separate `UINavigationController`; you can just set the title with

```
self.navigationItem.title = titleTextField.text;
```

If you set view controller as the delegate of the `UITextField`, and implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (textField == titleTextField) {
        self.navigationItem.title = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                             withString:string];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

you'll get a title which updates in real time. (Remember that this method is called *before* the `textField.text` actually changes, that's why there is a `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:` call in it.)

Comment: If I have multiple text fields on that page how would I choose which text field changes the title?

Comment: Just check if `textField == titleTextField` (or whatever that particular text field is called). See my updated answer.

Comment: Is this method being implemented inside the view controllers file or the text fields file?

Comment: Inside the view controller - you can just use standard UITextFields for this. Check [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-uitextfield-uitextfielddelegate--mobile-10943) to find out how text field delegates work in general.

Comment: I can't seem to get this working. I make the view a delegate of the text field by selecting the delegate and dragging it to the view. Then input this method into my ViewController.m. However when I run the simulation the text field does not change. Do i have to initialize the text field `titleTextField` and then pick which field it is?

Comment: If you are in the ViewController, you must do: `self.navigationItem.title = <myNewTitle>;`. Then, the NavigationController will get the new title from the ViewController.navigationItem.

Comment: @NicolasBuquet thanks - I forgot that the title is copied somewhere during the view load.

Comment: I must be setting the delegate wrong, if I'm in storyboard and click the text field then drag the delegate from the connections inspector to the view I am setting the view controller as a delegate of the text field, correct?

Comment: No, you're not. The `UIView` will be the delegate, then. You can drag it to the view controller icon in the top bar of the storyboard scene.